# About how to profiling with-stack-sampling:

Tags: scheme, profiling

Supposed MIT-Scheme 9.2 and these procedures:

```
(define (max x y) (if (<= x y) y x))
(define (maxall l) (reduce max 0 l))
```

the procedures are compiled (p. 51, Ch. 6 in User's Manual):

```
1 ]=> maxall
;Value 3: #[compiled-procedure 3 ("foo" #x4) #x3 #x1b9ee4]
```

and it works:

```
1 ]=> (maxall '(1 3 2))
;Value: 3
```

but profiling with **with-stack-sampling** failed:

```
1 ]=> (with-stack-sampling 10 maxall)
;Stack-sampling...
;The procedure #[compiled-procedure 3 ("foo" #x4) #x3 #x1b9ee4] has been called with 0 arguments; it requires exactly 1 argument.
;To continue, ...
```

Interpreter says wrong number of arguments, but I don't think so
because the usage of **with-stack-sampling** is described in p. 51 of [User's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user.pdf):

> with-stack-sampling *interval procedure* 
>   Applies *procedure* to zero arguments. ...,

How did I do wrong? and How should I apply the function to an argument with profiling it?

Comment: `(lambda () (maxall '(1 2 3)))`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.